# Apple News+ channel not findable in the App

Tags: icloud, news.app, apple-news

I'm in Canada.

My Apple News channel (KNITmuch) is not findable in the App. I've already tried to change my Apple ID region from Canada to USA, nothing happened.

If I go to my channel's Analytics in the iCloud dashboard, I'm getting some traffic from Canada, Australia, and UK but it's VERY VERY low compared with USA.

How is this possible?

Is Apple News and Apple News+ the same thing? I was able to find my channel a few months ago, now I noted the App name, icon and everything is different.

Could it be "available" in Apple News, but not in Apple News+?

Comment: Apple News+ is the paid, subscription service to Apple News.  Content varies based on your location.  It looks like this might be something that's best handled by Apple themselves, have you contacted them?

Comment: I tried but didn't receive any reply and the support forums' answers are too ambiguous. Just to clarify, News and News+ are both different things. Right?

Comment: News is the app and basic content.  News+ is the premium subscription service only.

Comment: Thank you! So it means a channel could be available on News, but not on News+. Is that what are you saying? @fsb